# How do I intercept a keyboard entry before it is entered into an edit box?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

How do I intercept a keyboard entry before it is entered into an edit box?  I have:

```
<Window x:Class="X.MainWindow"
        KeyDown="Window_KeyDown"
        >

private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Add) 
        return;
}//Window_KeyDown
```

Pressing the "+" button on the numeric section of the keyboard is detected.  It also places a "+" into one of my edit boxes.  How do I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already intercepted the key before it gets sent to the Textbox.

Now, set

```
e.Handled = true;
```

so that the event does not keep propagating up to the textbox

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled(v=vs.110).aspx

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Add) 
    {
        e.Handled = true; // Prevents the event from propagating further.
        return;
    }
}//Window_KeyDown
```

Answer (score 0):

If the keypressed is the letter/symbol you don't want to be entered, jsut add "e.Handled = true;" like

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Add) 
        e.Handled = true;
}//Window_KeyDown
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [`PreviewKeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event which raises before the `KeyDown` event, if a key is pressed you don't want set `e.Handled = true`, just note that if you set `e.Handled = true` in the `PreviewKeyDown` event, the `KeyDown` event will be considered handled aswel and will be supressed

Answer (score 0):

How about this to stop the entry into the combo box?

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
  e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
  e.Handled = true;
  return;
  //base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```